# Delete a custom item when the button in it get clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, listitem

I have a `ListView` with custom list items having following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TextView android:id="@+id/itemNumberText" 
               android:text="1." android:textSize="16sp"
               android:textStyle="bold" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="33dp" 
               android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/item"
               android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="47dp"/>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="143dp">

              <TextView android:text="name" 
                        android:id="@+id/text1" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:textSize="16sp" android:textStyle="bold"  
                        android:textColor="#f5cd10"></TextView>

             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                              android:text="amount" 
                              android:textColor="#ffffff"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView android:text=" unit" 
                              android:id="@+id/text4"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:text="price"
                      android:id="@+id/text3"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:onClick="itemDeleteButtonClicked" 
                    android:background="@drawable/item_button_style_selector" 
                    android:text="Delete Item" android:id="@+id/list_button" 
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As its seen from above I mentioned a method for Button, typing

```
android:onClick="itemDeleteButtonClicked"
```

Here's the code for method:

```
 public void itemDeleteButtonClicked(View v)
 {
    int index;
    index=itemsListView.getSelectedItemPosition();//itemsListView is the listview
    list.remove(index);//list is the list of data to be shown in listview
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

I have used a `SimpleAdapter` and it's not customized. Here it is:

```
//create base adapter for listview 
adapter= new SimpleAdapter( 
             this, list, R.layout.detailed_info_list_item, 
               new String[] {"number","item","amount","price","unit"}, 
               new int[] {R.id.itemNumberText,R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text3,R.id.text4} 
             ); 
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But it's not working. That is it's not deleting the clicked item. Would you please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The method `getSelectedItemPosition()` only returns the right value if the list item is really selected. If you press a Button inside the list item the list item probably wont be selected according to the list view. Check the value of the index Variable after you have called `getSelectedItemPosition()`. If it is -1 no list item is selected and you have to do the selection of the right list item yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Could you please suggest a way to get the actual selected item position?

Comment: You have to hand over a reference of the list item or an id to the OnButtonClickedListener. Then you can delete the correct list item in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `OnItemClickListener` on your listview to store the item position into a field then you will know which item was selected.

You could try calling setSelection to make getSelectedItemPosition work but setting a field is simpler